# NFT Enlisting on OpenSea

Tags: evm, nft, poa

I have implemented EVM and ETH Pallet in Substrate Based chain with POA consensus mechanism. Contracts deployment in Solidity language and NFT Minting transactions are also working perfectly but i'm unable to visualise Minted NFT's on openSea.
What should i do so i can enlist all minted NFT's of Substrate on OpenSea Marketplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask Opensea to list your network...

https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/4404027708051-Which-blockchains-are-compatible-with-OpenSea-

Comment: Thanks @AurevoirXavier For Answering.